# Salesforce HTML Email Template

Tags: salesforce, html-email, force.com

Just a general question regarding HTML Email Templates on Salesforce. I have researched various ways to incorporate an Email Template with HTML Markup but once I preview the email the HTML markup is displayed. Specifically, how do I place an HTML button to be displayed on an email template to be used for an email alert?
Thank you for your time and consideration

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a easy bullet proof email button, you can copy&paste this one.

```
<!-- Button -->
<table align="center" width="150">
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#F18200" width="150" style="border: 1px solid #DF7901;-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;">
<a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; border: 1px solid #F18200; display: inline-block; width:150px;">Apply Now &rarr;</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you need it centered, just wrap it in good ol center tags and that should do the trick. I've tested and works well for my sends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulletproof button

```html
<tr>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 0; font-size: 12px;color: #717171; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;">
     <!-- BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tbody><tr>
          <td align="center" style="padding-top: 16px;padding-bottom: 19px;" class="padding">
              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                 <tbody><tr>
                   <td align="center" style="border-radius: 2px;" bgcolor="#906197">
                       <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 2px; padding: 9px 15px; border: 1px solid #906197; display: inline-block;" class="mobile-button">REGISTER NOW</a>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                   </tbody></table>
                 </td>
               </tr>
             </tbody></table>
           </td>
         </tr>
```